shell or perl one liner to store tab separated values in two different variable
I have a tab-separated file like this:
test     test2
test3    test4

I want to read each line, store the first field in $a and 2nd in $b using a shell or Perl one liner. Because then I need to perform more operations on them separately. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks!

In bash:
while IFS=$'\t' read a b ; do
    echo "$a|$b"  # Or whatever else...
done < input.file

In Perl, using its -F auto-split functionality:
perl -F'\t' -lane '($a, $b) = @F; print "$a|$b"' < input.file

Both the examples work correctly even if the input file contains spaces inside the fields.

Might be worth noting that perl has auto-split functionality: printf 'a\tb\n' | perl -F'\t' -lane '($a, $b) = @F; ...'

@WilliamPursell: True, thanks. Updated.
